# Complicated C cast explanation

Tags: c, casting, void

I'm trying to figure out what the following code in C does?

```
((void(*)())buf)();
```

where 'buf' is a `char` array.

Comment: Look for a program called "cdecl".  Download it.  Paste the declaration into it.  Be enlightened.

Comment: @Paul: I shall try that and hope that it does not kill my machine!

Comment: This code might reasonably appear in a JIT, or in the OS in a dynamic linker/loader. As others have said, it's scary stuff, but only if you've encountered it in a typical application. In its proper place, it's not scary stuff, just difficult stuff.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Let's take it one step at a time.

```
void(*)()
```

This is a pointer to a function that takes unspecified arguments and has no return value.

```
(void(*)())buf
```

simply casts buf to this function pointer type. Finally,

```
((void(*)())buf)();
```

calls this function.

So the entire statement is "interpret `buf` as a pointer to a `void` function without arguments, and call that function."

Comment: Casting a character buffer into a function and calling it is evil.  It's either an attempt at self modifying code, or it's a malicious intent to do some sort of exploit.  Either way, avoid it at all costs.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't it the value of the pointer (the address of the array) that is treated as a function, not the contents of the array?  "interpret *the value* in buf" sounds a little bit like you're saying the contents are interpreted as a pointer to a function.

Comment: @Paul: more probably code generation, but still your complaints apply, of course. :)

Comment: I know it is malicious code, but I was just trying to understand it.  I would never use it!

Comment: @Nick Meyer: You're right, fixed it.
@pmg: Fixed that, too. I'll take your word for it, but do you have a reference?
Thank you both.

Comment: Note that C makes no guarantee that a data pointer has the same size as a function pointer.

Comment: @Thomas: 6.5.2.2/6 in n1401.pdf (the latest draft of the Standard). A function declaration without arguments does not provide a prototype; and `void(*)()` is such a declaration.

Comment: @vonolsson: Quite aside from pointer size, C makes no guarantee that memory allocated on either the stack or the heap is executable. This code should only appear in a JIT or equivalent, and necessarily is platform-specific. Assuming that buf has just been filled with machine instructions, the line before the quoted cast-and-call should probably be some kind of platform-specific operation to flush the icache.

Comment: @Paul Tomblin: seriously, avoid JITs at all cost? Or do you just mean, don't write them in C?

Comment: What could possible use of doing this eludes me?

Answer (score 9):

It casts `buf` to a function pointer of type `void(*)()` (A function returning nothing/void and taking unspecified arguments) and calls it.

The ANSI standard does not really allow the casting of normal data pointers to function pointers, but your platform may allow it.

Comment: How come you can cast an array to a function pointer?? Is there some article that explains it?

Comment: A pointer is just a collection of bytes like any other value (which can thus be presented in C as an array of chars). You'll probably find that elsewhere in the program the reverse of this was done: `char *buf = (char *)function;` or something similar.

Comment: You can do this because it's C -- you can do whatever you want.  It's a terrible idea, but you can do it.

Comment: What I'm saying is that it is not guaranteed to work. It is undefined behaviour in ANSI: On a Harvard architecture your program memory and data memory is physically separate, so a cast from a `char*` to a `void(*)()` does not make sense.

Comment: Even on a von Neumann architecture, if segmentation is being used then a data pointer and a function pointer with the same value might point to different memory (the MS-DOS "Small" memory model is a real example of this).

Answer (score 5):

I tend to use the "cdecl" command when I come across a mind boggling declaration. Example:

```
[me@machine]$ cdecl
Type `help' or `?' for help
cdecl> explain (void(*)())buf
cast buf into pointer to function returning void
```

Although there are cases where I do wish that there's a tool out there that explains the output of "cdecl" :/

Answer (score 4):

This casts `buf` to the type `void (*)()`, a pointer to a function that takes unspecified parameters and returns nothing.  Then it calls the function at that address (the two rightmost parentheses).

Answer (score 2):

It casts `buf` into a function pointer, that takes unspecified arguments, and calls it.

Answer (score 2):

```
((void(*)())buf)();
 \------------/         cast `buf` to
 \---------/            type: pointer to function accepting a fixed but
                              unspecified number of arguments and
                              returning void
\----------------/      and call that "function"
```

Comment: +1 You are correct about the unspecified number of parameters.  If you had clarified with an example, you'd probably have gotten more appreciation for your insight :)

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that in many circumstances, it crashes the machine.
Otherwise, it treats the array as a pointer to a function that returns void and invokes it.

Answer (score 1):

You might find "expert c programming" a good read - unpacking this kind of thing is in one of the chapters, if I remember right.  It's a long time since I read it, but I remember thinking it was worth the effort at the time.
[http://www.amazon.com/Expert-Programming-Peter-van-Linden/dp/0131774298](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131774298)

Answer (score 1):

There is an online version of the 'cdecl' tool that lsc mentioned that you might find useful : http://www.cdecl.org/

Answer (score 0):

calls a function pointer. the function has no arguments.

[Function Pointer - Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_pointer)

Comment: The function has (is given) no arguments. The function type has unspecified parameters.

Comment: Granted, given the other answers I'll leave the post as it is.